# HashMap is already sorted by key?

Tags: java

I thought that HashMap is unordered, and when iterating over the keys, you can't know what will be the order? In this example, it looks like the map is already sorted by the keys numbers:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] words = {"Car", "Cat" ,"Hello", "World", "Hi", "Bye", "Dog", "Be"};

    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (String word: words) {
        Integer len = word.length();
        List<String> l = map.get(len);
        if (l == null) { 
            l = new ArrayList<String>();
            l.add(word); 
            map.put(len, (ArrayList<String>) l);
        }
        else {
            if (! l.contains(word)) 
                l.add(word);
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
}
```

Output:

```
{2=[Hi, Be], 3=[Car, Cat, Bye, Dog], 5=[Hello, World]}
```

Comment: If you want to handle the order, use a TreeMap. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Being in order is just one of the permutations you could have.. Since you only have 3 elements in your map you have 16% chance of being in order.... (thanks to @OliCharlesworth)

Comment: There's no guarantee it *won't* have any particular order. There are almost no guarantees about order at all.

Comment: @gtgaxiola: 6 permutations, so only 16% chance ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are right!

Comment: OK, thank you guys, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something about the definition.

Comment: Expanding on @gtgaxiola's comment; just because we can't guarantee what the ordering is at a particular moment doesn't mean the ordering can't happen to take on a familiar form at some point or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True but there is no guarantee of maintaining that order.

> From [Hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) docs
>
> This class makes **no guarantees** as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order **will remain constant over time**.

Your bench mark is not enough to decide over it.

Look at [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) If you need the sorting order

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used

Answer (score 2):

For small hashCodes, the HashMap turns into an array (as this is what is used underneath)  There is no requirement for it to do so but it happens to be the simplest implementation.

In short, if you add 0 to 10 to a HashSet or HashMap you will get them in order because the capacity is large enough to just layout those values in order.

Comment: _HashMap turns into an array_ ... have to say, I never knew that; what's the limit before it morfs into its true form?

Comment: Not sure the 2nd statement is true. Counterexample:
String[] words = {"Car", "Cat" ,"Hello", "World", "Hi", "Dog", "Be", "BEAUTIFUL", "PROXIMITIY", "ANTIESTABLISHMENT"}; Gives: {17=[ANTIESTABLISHMENT], 2=[Hi, Be], 3=[Car, Cat, Dog], 5=[Hello, World], 9=[BEAUTIFUL], 10=[PROXIMITIY]}

Comment: It is really an array of list references, but in this case each list is contains only one element. For small hash code values, the array is effectively indexed by hash code. An Integer's hash code is its value. String hash code is more complicated.

Comment: @raffian For the default size, the limit is a hashCode of 15, or 11 elements.  If you increase the capacity you can increase this to 127 or 128*0.7 elements.

Comment: @gtgaxiola 15 is small enough, 17 is not small enough unless you increase the capacity.  Try `Map map = new HashMap(32);`

Answer (score 1):

Treemap is a sorted map which contains keys in sorted order and HashMap can't gurantee you sorted map.So,always choose Treemap when ever you want sorted keys